# PayPal Express Checkout Configuration in osCommerce 2.3

Tags: paypal, express

I am setting up a website using osCommerce 2.3. The site is close to completion so I set up a PayPal sandbox to test the transaction/payment process. I am using the PayPal Express Checkout module provided with osCommerce. I inserted the sandbox username, password and signature into the module and tried the credentials test link. The test failed and the test debug email showed that no data was being transmitted by either $_GET or $_POST. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I am using WampServer 2.2.22, a 64-bit version which contains a buggy version of the curl.dll. Curl was refusing to load, so when it was making the call to PayPal in the sendTransactionToGateway function in paypal_express.php, the function failed. Working 64-bit versions of curl can be found at http://www.anindya.com/ for php 5.3.13 and 5.4.3. Replacing the old version of curl with the new one and restarting wampserver did the trick.